# Can we go back to our home country then come back to the UK for six months?

Tags: visas, uk, legal

I am a Philippine passport holder, currently in the UK since November 6. I went overseas twice and came back as I need to stay here for the maximum of 180 days. I have a 5-year multiple-visit visa. Can I spend 1 month or less in my home country after my 180days, then come back to the UK?

This is my third visa. I'm married to a British citizen since 2015 but we lived overseas before coming to the UK. Full-time housewife.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

**Nope**, Don't do that even if you theoretically can.

Your situation is a textbook example of a person who would want to live in the UK for an extended period of time using successive visits. You will get yourself in trouble. It's better to apply for the appropriate visa, which allows you to live there longer.

Whatever is possible in theory is not necessarily always fine in practice.

You've good history with them and your spouse is British, use both of those things to your benefit and apply for the visa that lets you relocate to the UK.

Comment: To add to the above a multiple-visit visa is not a multiple-entry visa. As per new rules you can still be denied entry at the border if the border officer is convinced you are likely to be violating the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a class of visa which allows for it, you have to convince the UK immigration officer at the border that you are not attempting to live in the UK via successive long-term visits - if they suspect this, you will be denied, your visa cancelled and you could be banned.

> Your visa may be cancelled and you may get a long-term ban on visiting if your travel history shows you’re repeatedly living in the UK for extended periods.

[UK Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility)

So it all depends on the validity of your reason for having to return to the UK after a recent long-term visit.